# How do I Install FreeMat 4.1 on 12.10 32 bit?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, source-code, freemat

How do I install **FreeMat 4.1** on **12.10 32 bit**?

The **latest version** available in the software centre or from other **debian package** sources is **4.0**.

Using **Alien** on the **rpm** package available at [FreeMat Sourceforge](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/) **doesn't work** because it is **64 bit**. I've tried to use the source code release but it wasn't in the form I knew how to install it. (That is with configure and makefiles)

Installing from source code seems like the only viable method of installing it but I just don't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just on the Freemat site and I did see two RPM files, one was a 64 bit version (_64.rpm) but there also was a presumably 32 bit version as well.  Did you try the one without the _64 on the end?

Hope this helps!

Jonathan

Comment: could you share the link to where to download the 32 bit rpm file?

Comment: I have searched the website extensively and I haven't seen a 32 bit rpm file

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemat/files/FreeMat4/FreeMat-4.1.fc14.i686.rpm/download

Comment: I think that may be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks, rofl, I can't believe I couldn't see it.

Comment: Hey just one more thing before I approve your answer, how do I run freemat?

Comment: I have installed it using alien but now I can't seem to run it

Comment: you know - I don't know, I have always wanted to try it, but I have been focused on my CNC tools and havent taken the time.

Comment: No worries on not seeing it!  It happens to me all the time!